# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS running slow

Tags: 16.04

Running slow means booting takes more time than earlier . Also opening terminal takes more to see the prompt.

I've attached the screenshot of the output of `sudo lshw -c video`

[image: screenshot of the output of sudo lshw -c video]

Comment: Even opening firefox takes incredibly long time.   Tried to decrease swappiness value set to 10. But the sloppiness remains same

Answer (score 0):

Install a desktop that uses lesser resources like Lubuntu or Xubuntu. To install lubuntu type the following in terminal:

```
sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop
```

To install xubuntu, type the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop
```